# How can we find the upload path of an attachment at the time of email transfer?

Tags: email, smtp

I am capturing SMTP packets being transferred when sending an e-mail from my machine.
In the packets I get only filename of the attachment attached to the e-mail and not the complete path of the file.

Is there any way to get complete path (file path on machine) of the attachment?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible!

When the email is being sent, the attachment has already been read by the email program and only the filename without path is used (primarily just to tell the receiver what to call the attached file). There is nothing in the email itself that needs a path to the file.